# VB.Net Transferring A Windows Form App Onto A USB Stick

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am just wondering how do you transfer a windows form application onto a flash drive because every time I have tried after its transferred I click to open it and an error message displays saying:

"Cannot find the file 'F:\Vending Machine.vb.'

I need to be able to transfer it so when it opens I am able to edit the code and the appearance of the application as I would if I were to just open a new windows form application now.

Thank you

Marcus.

Comment: If you are moving C:\users\etc\projects\myproject to F:\ I am confused as to why it would be looking for F:\file.vb. The only thing on the root should be F:\FolderForProject.

Comment: What should I do?, I need the programme for class next week

Comment: Well, read the error message.  Do *you* see that file in the F:\ directory?  If not, where is actually located?

Comment: There are two other messages it also displays: F:\Vending Machine\Vending Machine.vbproj : error  : Unable to read the project file 'Vending Machine.vbproj'. 
                                                                   F:\Vending Machine\Vending Machine.vbproj: The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path 'F:\Vending Machine\Vending Machine.vbproj'.

Comment: It seems like you are not moving the file correctly or the initial project is onfused about where to look for files. Based on your other error messages you dont sseem to be moving the entire project. See my answer

Comment: for some reason those files it needs are not in the actual project folder but in my documents, why would it be there?

Comment: Are you referencing files in your project? To move everything over you will have to reconfigure your project so the files are all in one place or you will have to recreate the same type of environment on the flashdrive.

Comment: the vending machine.designer.vb file, the vending machine.net managed resources file and the vending machine.vb files are in my documents

Answer (score 0):

You will need to transfer the entire project/solution to the USB.

Transfering the already compiled .exe should open the latest build of your application. Transferring only a portion of the solution folder and then trying to open the .sln will cause errors on the files you have left out.

1. Clear your FlashDrive
2. Copy the entire folder(not the contents) to your flashdrive (C:\Users\Marcus's MPC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Vending Machine)
3. Attempt to open the .sln

Based on your additional comments it seems you are not moving all of the files the solution needs. If you have files stored in other locations (like My Document) those will need to be reconfigured to work with the solution or you will have to mimic the environment.

I would recommend reconfiguring the project to consolidate any stray files you have.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I go into C:\Users\Marcus's MPC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Vending Machine and copy the entire project onto the flash drive but it does not work, still displays an error message, I have tried this many times but everytime there is the same error

Comment: Are you copying the "Vending Machine" directory or are you going inside and moving all files to the root of the flash drive?

Comment: I am copying the entire vending machine project folder onto the flash drive.

Comment: the project folder does not contain a .sln file.

Comment: how would I reconfigure the project to consolidate the stray files?

Comment: You can recreate the project so your files are all in one place or you can manually move them all into the correct place (this might require changes paths in your code). Depending on how "strayed" your files are you may just want to restart the project and copy and paste your code verifying that you are adding class files etc to the proper location.

Comment: i have pressed save as, instead of saving in my documents should i save in the vending machine project folder?

Comment: Hey sealz thanks for your help, it now works all i needed to do was after i pressed save as instead of saving in my documents i saved in the vending machine project folder, thanks :)

Comment: Yes save should just default to the proper place. Good luck!